# ASP.NET MVC JsonResult how to update View from url Http Get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, jsonresult

I am confusing about HTTP GET method in ASP.NET MVC.

Normally, if I create a View -> click button -> call controller -> controller returns JsonResult -> javascript gets the JsonResult and populate table in the View: everything works just fine.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lN7w.png)

However, if instead of clicking the button, I directly call the HTTP Get by url (let's say: https://localhost:44378/MyController/Action?ID=123), then in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Action(string ID)
{
    var Info = new List<MyModel>();
    //some DB work here

    return Json(Info, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then what I receive once I enter the url is only a screen filled with Json string. How could I make a view with table filled as expected?

I thought of passing the json string to JS using Viewbag, but I think there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: Well - your method **does** return JSON - since you have `return Json(...)`  - if you want a view - then use `return View(.....)`....

Comment: Yes. If I return a View, how could I pass the data from controller to the view in this case? Giving that I acces the action by url, not by clicking an input on the view.

Comment: `return View(Info)` - you need to define a model type on your view, and when calling the `View()` method, provide a compatible data variable of that type

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks.